# "I do nothing but!" acceptable ellipsis?

Tags: ellipsis

> A: You probably do that a lot, don't you?
>
> B: I do nothing but!

Does that ellipsis in B's answer sound correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may sound a little clipped to a non-native, but there's nothing wrong with it. It's only really eliding one word:

> You probably do that a lot, don't you?
>
> I do nothing but [that]!

As the object (that) is obvious from context, it isn't strictly necessary to include it in the sentence and it can be elided safely.

Comment: As John Cifford's answer says, you could get away with this, but I wouldn't overuse it. Also, for this construct to work verbally, the exclamation mark is important, and there's a rather heavy emphasis on the last word: “I do nothing ***but***!” (If you emphasized the word _nothing_ instead, the sentence wouldn't sound correct with just the "but" at the end; it would sound like your thought train was interrupted mid-sentence.)

Answer (score 2):

Here in this context that *but* at the end of the sentence might take a NP as ellipsis,like this -

- I do nothing but *(that)*.

But that is not always the case. Let me quote from Fowler's Modern English Usage -

> > **but** at end of sentence -
>
> One of the most surprising and largely uncharted modern uses of
>   **but** is its occurrence as a qualifying adverb at the end of sentences. Taking a lead from the Scots and the Irish,
>   not-quite-standard speakers in Australia, in some parts of South
>   Africa, and perhaps elsewhere provide evidence of this construction
>   which has not yet entered the standard English of England:
>
> - 'He should have left the key with me,' she said. 'I'm his wife.' 'I didn't ask for it, but.'-M. Richler, 1980 (Canad.)
> - 'I been waiting round for years and years and I still don't know what it is, but.'-M. Eldridge, 1984 (Aust.)
> - Yes, I told 'im. Not the whole of it, but.'— D. Malouf, 1985 (Aust.);
> - "That was a lovely cat, but' [ = that was a truly lovely cat] — R. Mesthrie, 1987 (SAfr.);

[This article](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=119) provides some more info, and its meaning -

> - contrastive meaning ('though')
> - intensive meaning ('really')
> - in most of the cases, a particle used for interactive reasons to show the other speaker he/she can speak.